# How to mask angular routes to symbolic paths

Tags: angular, routes

so I'm trying to develop a UI for a custom plugin. The way it works is that an existing UI creates an iframe and loads my plugin ui in there. I'm using Angular to create this UI and also am using routes to navigate between the different pages.
This works fine ind development when I'm testing the UI for itself. But in production the 'parent' UI will call the plugin ui with a symbolic url path like `/api/pluginui/pluginname/index.html?variousParameters=123456`
And that's when the routing fails, since api/pluginui/... are not valid paths (as in 'directories').
Of course `path: '**'` works to get my plugin ui to load, but all the assets relate to the old path.

What do you think is the best approach?
It does seem that the symbolic path is static, so I could add this in the routing module. But I would prefer to create a matcher, so that it uses the symbolic path and just acts as if it was `/`, `/login` and so on.

Thx, for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Found a suitable answer myself:

for development I'll use the '/' base reference.

And for production you can set a different path with `ng build --base-href /relative/path/on/the/server/`